# How to find a specific class that contains another class?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<div class="accordion mobile ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" role="tablist">
    <h3 class="accord-**19** **ui-state-active**"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s">Title 1</h3>
        <div style="" class="ui-accordion-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-accordion-content-active" id="ui-id-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
            Content for title 1
        </div>
        <h3 class="accord-41">Title 2</h3>
        <div style="display: none;" class="ui-accordion-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">
            Content for title 2
        </div>
        <h3 class="accord-47">Title 3</h3>
        <div style="display: none;" class="ui-accordion-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-6" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">
            Content for title 3
        </div>        
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is:

- Get the h3 tag that contains the class ui-state-active
  and then
- Get the unique id  (in this example, 19) that comes after the class name that starts with "accord-".

Note, the above is churned out by a plugin I am using, which means I cannot set and "id" tag for h3 to be unique.

I have tried:

`var classname = $("div.accordion h3.ui-state-active").find('class^="accord-"');`

To get the name of the class, before I substring it.
However, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you tried to retrieve the class name `.find`  was not the correct way to do it. To find the attributes of an element you should use `.attr`, and then specify `.attr("class")` to find classes. Then from there use regex to find the correct `accord-id`.

```
var classname = $("div.accordion h3.ui-state-active").attr("class");
var id = classname.match(/accord-(\d+)/)[0];
```